# Cannot use `req.body` to get form data in express.js

Tags: ajax, forms, express

I have a form with some input and selection field to get user data. And i want to send ajax call through the submit button's handler to persist user data to server.

Here is the skeleton of the code,

Client side:

```
xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true)
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      log('ajax succeed')
    } else {
      log('ajax failed')
    }
  }
}
console.log(data) // the data is not empty
xhr.send(data)
```

Server side:

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) // get "{}"
  res.send('greetings from Express!')
})
```

The ajax call does reach the server endpoint and can properly send the message back to client, but why can't i get those form data from `req.body`?

Comment: Any hints on what `data` looks like?

Comment: @Phil data shape like this: `{ username, uploaded_file, selected_options }`

Comment: So `data` is an actual JavaScript object? Are you wanting to send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (what you're attempting to do currently) or as JSON?

Comment: @Phil Yes, it is JS object. I just want to hook up with the backend apis first, as i need those as params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you aren't sending the right body format for the content-type you're telling the server to expect so it cannot parse the data.

Try this (client-side)

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
```